# Prove there is a deterministic sequence for which $\frac{X_n}{c_n}\overset{a.s.}{\to}0$.

Tags: probability

Prove that for any sequence $X_1,X_2,\dots$ of random variables there exists a deterministic sequence $c_1,c_2,\dots$ of real numbers for which $\frac{X_n}{c_n}\overset{a.s.}{\to}0$.

So far my idea has been to try to use the Borel-Cantelli lemma to show this. I want to show that there is a sequence such that
$$
P\left(\frac{X_n}{c_n}\geq\frac1n\right)\leq\frac1{n^2},
$$
and then I could use Borel-Cantelli to finish off from here. The problem is that I'm not sure how to show that this sequence exists without having any assumptions on the random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$ Does this require that I assume the random variables are finite? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We have $\lim_{x\to+\infty}P(X_n\geq x)=0$. So some $x>0$ with $P(X_n\geq x)\leq\frac1{n^2}$ can be found. Then let $c_n=nx$.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the hint. However, technically, I think in your last equation you should use, for instance, $\epsilon=\frac{1}{l}$ rather than $\frac{1}{n}$. In the lemma $\epsilon$ has nothing to do with the index of the series.